# issue while using sambag time picker

Tags: ios, swift

i am using sambag time picker controller and i am set time on button on method of sambag picker but issue is that i have multiple buttons in one view controller so i did this for every but on set time method at the time of set button all buttons title are change what i want is that only change value of button which i pressed

here i will show you what i tried i will show you with my code

```
   import UIKit

   class ManageHoursViewController: UIViewController {

     var theme: SambagTheme = .light

    var result : String!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMonStartTime: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMonEndTime: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMonOff: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMonOn: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        round()

        let hh2 = (Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()))
        let mm2 = (Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date()))
        print(hh2)
        print(mm2)
        let dateTime = "\(hh2) : \(mm2)"
        btnMonStartTime.setTitle("\(dateTime)", for: .normal)
        btnMonEndTime.setTitle("\(dateTime)", for: .normal)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func round(){

        btnMonOff.isHidden = true
        btnMonStartTime.layer.cornerRadius = btnMonStartTime.frame.height / 2
        btnMonStartTime.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 154/255, green: 154/255, blue: 154/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        btnMonStartTime.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        btnMonStartTime.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        btnMonStartTime.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        btnMonStartTime.layer.masksToBounds = false

        btnMonEndTime.layer.cornerRadius = btnMonEndTime.frame.height / 2
        btnMonEndTime.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 154/255, green: 154/255, blue: 154/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        btnMonEndTime.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        btnMonEndTime.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        btnMonEndTime.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        btnMonEndTime.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }

    @IBAction func btnMonStartTimeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = SambagTimePickerViewController()
        vc.theme = theme
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func btnMonEndTimeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = SambagTimePickerViewController()
        vc.theme = theme
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
extension ManageHoursViewController : SambagTimePickerViewControllerDelegate {

    func sambagTimePickerDidSet(_ viewController: SambagTimePickerViewController, result: SambagTimePickerResult) {
        self.result = "\(result)"
        print(self.result)
        btnMonStartTime.setTitle(self.result, for: .normal)
        btnMonEndTime.setTitle(self.result, for: .normal)
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func sambagTimePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: SambagTimePickerViewController) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

i want like when monday start time button press then and i select time form picker then only monday start time button value change at now all button value changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a var to track last clicked one

```
 var lastBu: UIButton!


    @IBAction func btnMonStartTimeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = SambagTimePickerViewController()
        vc.theme = theme
        vc.delegate = self
        lastBu = sender
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    }
    @IBAction func btnMonEndTimeTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = SambagTimePickerViewController()
        vc.theme = theme
        vc.delegate = self
        lastBu = sender
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: then on lastBu i can able to set title for particular button right?

Comment: Yes Thank You :)